# Parallax effect for a footer in android

Tags: android, android-animation, parallax, android-coordinatorlayout

Is there a way to implement footer parallax effect in Android? I know it's possible to implement header parallax with `CoordinatorLayout` + `AppBarLayout`. I wonder if it's possible to make a scroll animation of footer view like here https://codepen.io/hudsonmarinho/pen/FHGeK

Answer (score 0):

I implemented that by adding a fake transparent element in the adapter of RecyclerView. The height of the fake element should be equal to the footer height. The footer view should be placed above RecyclerView in a FrameLayout